# Setting a new Float at the exact place in the code

Tags: floats

I am using the following code for reporting algorithms.

```
\usepackage{caption}
\floatstyle{ruled}
\newfloat{Algorithm}{thp}{lop}
\floatname{Algorithm}{Algorithm}
\newcommand{\listofAlgorithms}{\listof{Algorithm}{Algo List}}
.....


Here my explanation 1

\begin{Algorithm}[!ht]
\begin{verbatim}
here my algo 1
\end{verbatim}
\caption{Encrypt}
\end{Algorithm}

Here my explaination2

\begin{Algorithm}[!ht]
\begin{verbatim}
here my algo 2
\end{verbatim}
\caption{Encrypt2}
\end{Algorithm}
```

However sometimes the represented algorithm is not placed at the same place than in the code. What I mean is that it is going on the next page, leaving the text above.

I would like to keep the same code but with algorithms at the exact place. That is to say that breaking algorithm between would be possible 2 pages is possible.
How can I do it?

Indeed, on my example, it is displayed as such on the pdf:

```
 Here my explanation1
 Here my explanation2
 here my algo1
 here my algo2
```

I do not want to refer the algorithm to a special place.

Comment: See [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017) and [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned]. (http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2275). `Algorithm` is just another type of float, so the above apply.

Comment: @egreg: I tried with [!htbp] but sadly it's not working. IMO the algorithm can not be split, therefore going on the other page.

Comment: No floating object can be split across pages.

Comment: Ok then how can I set the text at the right place? Because if I type some text between 2 algorithm, the text is not displayed betwen them, but before.

Comment: @user23710 You have obviously not read the threads where egreg pointed you to. The algorithm is placed at the top or bottom, and it has a number so that you can refer to it by this number (using `\label` and `\ref`).

Comment: @tohecz First, it is not true, since I read a part of it, maybe I am not explaining myself clearly enough. I **want** to have some text between 2 algorithms, but it is not displayed as such and the text is going on the previous page, then are displayed the 2 algorithms. I do not want referring it! Please note I am not english native, explaining my issues understanding all the article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using the `float` package, use the `H` placement specifier to force the floats to appear exactly "Here":

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}

\floatstyle{ruled}
\newfloat{Algorithm}{thp}{lop}
\floatname{Algorithm}{Algorithm}
\newcommand{\listofAlgorithms}{\listof{Algorithm}{Algo List}}

\begin{document}

\begin{Algorithm}[H]
\begin{verbatim}
here my algo
\end{verbatim}
\caption{First}
\end{Algorithm}
Some text between the two algorithms
\begin{Algorithm}[H]
\begin{verbatim}
here my algo
\end{verbatim}
\caption{Second}
\end{Algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want this behaviour for *all* of the `Algorithm` environments, add to the preamble:

```
\floatplacement{Algorithm}{H}
```

As a side note, there's a number of existing packages designed to facilitate the typesetting of algorithms; depending on the style of algorithms you want to typeset (using pseudo-code or code), you could be interested in [`algorithms`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/algorithms), [`algorithmicx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx), [`minted`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/minted) or [`listings`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings).